# Что лучше использовать для загрузки данных - AsyncTask или AsyncTaskLoader

Tags: android, android-asynctask, listview

Есть таск, который подгружает некоторые строки из страницы в интернете, и после должен выводить их в `ListView`. Подскажите, что лучше для этого использовать, обычный `AsyncTask` или `AsyncTaskLoader`? Потому что начал делать с `AsyncTask` и вроде работает, но узнал о существовании специально созданного для этой работы класса.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Использовать класс `AsyncTaskLoader` предпочтительнее, так он позволяет лучше управлять загрузкой через `LoaderManager`, безболезненно переносит изменение состояния (повороты устройства), кроме того появляется возможность следить за изменением данных и [другие преимущества](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120813/asynctaskloader-vs-asynctask).