# Сохранение состояния AsyncTask в AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-loader

Унаследовал свой активити от AppCompatActivity, в нем при нажатии кнопки запускается AsyncTask все работает и проблем нет!

Но при повороте (естественно) активити уничтожается и то, что делает AsyncTask перестает отображаться! Мне нужно чтоб на активити продолжал отображаться процесс после поворота!

Нашел пример, когда состояние  AsyncTask сохраняют при помощи метода `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` 
Но в AppCompatActivity этого метода нет, а `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` намекает ,что он устарелый! 
Примера как сохранять состояния AsyncTask в AppCompatActivity не нашел

**Возник вопрос:**  как реализовать сохранение состояния AsyncTask в AppCompatActivity ??? Или лучше  использовать **AsyncTaskLoader** вместо AsyncTask ???

Comment: Да, [лучше использовать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/473098/177345) `AsyncTaskLoader`.

Comment: @pavlofff, об AsyncTask можно забыть и вместо него всегда использовать AsyncTaskLoader?

Comment: @pavlofff, использую AsyncTaskLoader, и возник такой вопрос : как получать промежуточные данные ?

Comment: Вот как раз для случая с промежуточным обновлением UI-потока AsyncTaskLoader никак не приспособлен. Вы могли бы вызывать задачу в doInBackground() через запуск UI-потока (runOnUiTread()), но это не будет корректно работать при поворотах. Можно использовать любой способ "развязанной" отсылки данных:Handler, Message, LocalBroadcast, EventBus. Это конечно печаль, что в реализации не предусмотрели такого случая.

Comment: @pavlofff, ну вот такая беда что все-таки надо промежуточные данные(( прийдеться вернутся к AsyncTask и вопрос об сохранении состояния опять актуален( Что-то в мене никак не получается сохранить состояние (

Comment: Посмотрите [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428687/177345) и лекцию Калиты, на которую там ссылка. В лекции (ближе к концу) как раз рассматривается случай с отдельным потоком закачки из сети и сохранением его состояния. Возможно такой вариант вам подойдет.

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо ! будем искать )

Comment: вот [это видео на YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cH9UxmZwGO4), без регистрации (начиная с 33 минуты)

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо....очень интересные лекции)